# Is it possible to host email and DNS on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, amazon-web-services

We are working towards moving our app to AWS. I have heared that email and DNS cannot be hosted on AWS, is this correct?

If this correct, then what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS can be hosted on Amazon EC2. I've tried running both Microsoft DNS and BIND. One challenge you might run into would be the dynamic IP address of the DNS server. The IP address of an EC2 instance changes every time you terminate the instance and then relaunch it. The simplest solution to that conundrum would be to associate your DNS server with an Amazon Elastic IP address.

Comment: This is a good post from the awesome Shlomo :). Good tips for email from ec2.
http://www.shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-ec2.html

Comment: Reverse DNS for Elastic IP Addresses:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/03/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses.html

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at the specific services Amazon now offer for this functionality, [Route 53 for DNS hosting](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) and [Amazon Simple Email Service for outbound bulk email](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). If you are looking for a mail server for incoming and non-bulk outgoing use I imagine hosting a mail server on EC2 with an elastic IP address would be possible but may run into blacklisting issues.

Answer (score 2):

There's no big point in hosting email on EC2 cause most of the Amazon's IP addresses are already black-listed for spam unless you're ready to scan spam-listing services and clear them out.

Comment: OK. Cool, I will get a VPS for a mail server.

Comment: It may be cheaper for you to use something like SendGrid or PostMark. AWS also has the Simple Email Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill this form on the AWS site to remove the default limitations for sending email from EC2:
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request .